# UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad decimal button capped at half width

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit

I use the `UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad` in one of my apps, but when running on iOS 8 the comma button is capped at half width.

[image]

I tried creating a simple app with only a `UITextField` and the `DecimalPad` keyboard (in both Objective-C and Swift), it exhibits the same issue. Is this a bug in UIKit? I have not been able to find much information online, and iOS 8 has been out quite a while now. In iOS 7 the same code displays correctly.

Comment: Does the same thing happen on device?

Comment: Yes, it's identical on device. At least in the app I was working on when I ran into the issue. Didn't bother running the test app on device, but I will as soon as I'm within reach of an iPhone cable.

Comment: It's identical when running on device.

Comment: ...and...so...? have you reported it via radar?

Comment: @holex Yes, I have made a radar report. Perhaps more people should do so if this is in deed a bug and not some obscure configuration/localization issue. It seems very reproducible to me at least.

Comment: Just got it confirmed as a duplicate of a previous bug report (18078636) by Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really annoying oversight from Apple. The only real solution will come from them. 
Otherwise use the number pad and add the '.'. I did that before the DecimalPad came out.

Comment: In deed! I've actually been using an implementation made circa iOS 3 using the NumberPad + superimposed NSButton for the comma that stopped working with a recent iOS update. Too bad DecimalPad was fine up until iOS 7 and then just started looking weird. At least they seem to be aware of the issue, for what it's worth.